# How to whitelist prometheus metrics in a cleaner way if there are more than 1000 metrics that I wish to keep?

Tags: regex, yaml, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I know in prometheus I can keep only specific metrics in jobs as below

```yaml
metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__name__]
    regex: (?i)(metric1|metric2|metric3)
    action: keep
```

However there will be times when it will contain 500+ or 1000+ metrics in one job, I don't like the way where I add regex pattern for group of metrics and again add some more specific metrics where regex is not applicable.
Basically I want to avoid my regex look like this
(metric1|metric2|metric3|...| metric1000)

At the moment I tried simply adding all 500+ number of regex in config file, I can regex them all and lower them to may be 400 or 450 if i add regex inside a regex, but that does not make it look pretty.

I am expecting if there is way to call these regex from a file or create each file for separate jobs or use a global template of regex which can be called throughout the config file in any regex config value which will allow user to use a group of whitelisted metrics instead of group of regex for each job or any better solution.

I am exactly looking for a prometheus based solution and not any kind of python code which does this task in python way.

Comment: To be clear, you added helm tag because you use it to deploy prometheus now, or because you want help to start using it?

Comment: You are right, I used helm to deploy it. Am hoping whatever solution anyone provides I can discuss it on helm perspective as well.

Comment: Build a regex trie

Comment: So you will be OK with solution that has the same regex, but in separate file (for chart only, prometheus will have the same config as now after deploy)?

Comment: Can you answer if it's OK, if your whatever-long regex is used in actual Prometheus config multiple times, but is kept in helm chart clean? Or do you looking for a way to keep actual "compiled" config of Prometheus clean of it too?